# TProxy iptables error

Tags: iptables, haproxy

Hello i am using a vps (openvz) with Centos 6.4
I am trying to add the following rules for HaProxy TProxy but i got some errors (iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.)
Any idea?

```
[root@server1 ~]# iptables -t mangle -N DIVERT
[root@server1 ~]# iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m socket -j DIVERT
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
[root@server1 ~]# iptables -t mangle -A DIVERT -j MARK --set-mark 111
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
[root@server1 ~]# iptables -t mangle -A DIVERT -j ACCEPT
[root@server1 ~]# ip rule add fwmark 111 lookup 100
[root@server1 ~]# ip route add local 0.0.0.0/0 dev lo table 100
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use these modules unless your hosting provider allows for it. You need to contact your provider, or use anything other than OpenVZ/Virtuozzo.

Comment: Which modules should my provider enable ?